# CSS Star outline

Tags: css

Is there any way to make a css star shape outline?

I know you can make a filled in one, with the following css

```
    .star-five {
       margin: 50px 0;
       position: relative;
       display: block;
       color: red;
       width: 0px;
       height: 0px;
       border-right:  100px solid transparent;
       border-bottom: 70px  solid red;
       border-left:   100px solid transparent;
       -moz-transform:    rotate(35deg);
       -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
       -ms-transform:     rotate(35deg);
       -o-transform:      rotate(35deg);
    }
.star-five:before{
...
}
.star-five:after {
...
}
```

Working example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YXe3k/104/)

But what about a transparent fill with a red outline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an SVG:

```html
<svg width="320" height="320"><path  d="
M 160.000 180.000
L 183.511 192.361
L 179.021 166.180
L 198.042 147.639
L 171.756 143.820
L 160.000 120.000
L 148.244 143.820
L 121.958 147.639
L 140.979 166.180
L 136.489 192.361
L 160.000 180.000
" stroke="#f00" stroke-width="1" fill="none"/></svg>
```

I used this site to generate it if it helps: http://www.smiffysplace.com/stars.html

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help :) @SK2017

Answer (score 4):

I know this isn't quite the answer you were looking for, but I'm gonna post it anyway. For my knowledge there's no way of doing this with pure CSS. However, in my website I took a more easy approach. I had to style a rating bar with stars. Instead of creating the star with CSS, I simply did this:

```
<span>☆</span>
```

You can style this star however you like (and even fill it with the CSS `content` property).

[image]

Hope this help, and looking forward to see the other answers here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already seen these, the only thing wrong with these are when you enlarge them, they are not very star-like, due to them having near-square points.

Comment: You could use a font icon set like Font-Awesome. They are scalable vector graphics so you can blow them up as large as you please: http://fontawesome.io/icon/star-o/

Comment: @SK2017 Are you sure? I'm using this with `font-size:40pt` and it looks great, with perfect pointy edges.

Comment: @KobyDouek can you show me? I am using inspect element on your answer to enlarge font and the points aren't pointy

Comment: @SK2017 I will upload an image to my answer. Anyway - Don't use inspect element, just try it on your HTML site with a large font, it will work.

Comment: @KobyDouek ah, yes, just tried it, works perfect also!

Comment: @SK2017 I'm happy for you! Good luck with your project.

Comment: @KobyDouek Thanks dude!

Comment: how exactly are you able to fill that?

Comment: @UAvalos Like I wrote in my answer: "and even fill it with the CSS `content` property"

Comment: I can imagine UAvalos was asking for code snippet or at least an explanation. Are you able to show us what you mean, @KobyDouek?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure CSS solution using the same Fiddle you provided. I just scaled a star in and made it white.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.star-five {
  margin: 50px 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: red;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid red;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  -moz-transform: rotate(35deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(35deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(35deg);
}

.star-five:before {
  border-bottom: 80px solid red;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 0;
  top: -45px;
  left: -65px;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-35deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-35deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-35deg);
}

.star-five:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  color: red;
  top: 3px;
  left: -105px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid red;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-70deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-70deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-70deg);
  content: '';
}

.star-outline>.star-five,
.star-outline>.star-five:before,
.star-outline>.star-five:after {
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

.star-outline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="star">
  <span class="star-five" width="10" height="10">
</span>

  <div class="star-outline">
    <span class="star-five">
</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the body needs to be transparent

Comment: Well, would that be possible? I tried workarounds but couldnt get past this

Comment: It doesn't seem that it is possible in plain css, hence the question

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS properties:

```
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;   
-webkit-text-stroke-color: red;
```

Visualization:
[image: Border around the starts]
Hope this could help ~ RDaksh